# Allocating value of select query to variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm simply trying to give the result of a query to a declared variable. Something is not working, but I have no clue why it does not work.

```
DECLARE @Regime VARCHAR(2)

SELECT @Regime = (SELECT TOP 1 [H999C-CAETWK]
FROM [TC].[V_SSCAET]
WHERE [EM08I-CAIDWK] = @Employer
ORDER BY 99999999-[ARCHD-CAETWK_38] DESC)
```

When running the subquery on its own, it returns the correct value. Somehow, that value is not allocated to the varibale. When in debugging mode, the variable remains without a value.

Comment: There's a ninja variable here that might be causing trouble.

Comment: This code works as advertised, which leads naturally to the question how you determine that it doesn't work. What's the broader context where you actually use `@Regime`? What's the value of `@Employer`? How are you running the queries in both cases?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, '@Regime' is used in a further case statement. When '@Regime = 'xx' THEN a ELSE b'.
The value of '@Employer' is set by a select fetched into a cursor.
Also my example query is ran inside of the cursor

Comment: Include actual code in your question; don't describe it here in comments. Often the difference between working code and non-working code is something very minor and can only be spotted with the actual details visible. All we can tell from what you've posted here is that it *ought* to work -- `SELECT @var = (SELECT ...)` definitely assigns a variable.

Comment: The fact that you are using a cursor here is an even bigger indication of things that need some help. Looping should be avoided in nearly all situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Create table [V_SSCAET] ( [H999C-CAETWK] Varchar(2), [EM08I-CAIDWK] Varchar(20), [ARCHD-CAETWK_38] INT)

Insert Into [V_SSCAET] Values ('AC', 'ABC Employer', 15)

DECLARE @Regime VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Employer VARCHAR(20)

SET @Employer = 'ABC Employer'

SELECT @Regime = (SELECT TOP 1 [H999C-CAETWK]
FROM [V_SSCAET]
WHERE [EM08I-CAIDWK] = @Employer
ORDER BY 99999999-[ARCHD-CAETWK_38]  DESC)

SELECT @Regime AS Regime
```

Here is the live [demo](https://rextester.com/HWR86336).